# Error con Local data infile MYSQL

Tags: base-de-datos, csv, mysql-workbench

Estoy tratando de importar datos desde un archivo csv a una base de datos en mysql por medio del siguiente codigo

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'direccion del archivo' INTO TABLE nombre_tabla
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Pero al momento de ejecutarlo me aparece el siguiente mensaje

```
the used command is not allowed with this mysql version
```

Estoy usando MYSQL WORKBENCH

Comment: que versión de mysql usas? por que el error indica que en tu versión ese comando no esta disponible

Comment: workbench es solo una interfaz gráfica para trabajar con el gestor de bases de datos, por favor añade la versión del server que usas

Comment: Uso MySQL server 8.0